# how do i search twitter users by the URL given in account's info?

Tags: php, python, twitter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKmbv.png

i got many urls, like: http://www.aspli.com

all there urls are stated in twitter's accounts' info just like shown on the screenshot.

How do I get the username of the account?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if multiple users have the same URL in their twitter account?

Comment: that's right, thanks for your response.